# Python, Queue for sharing data between TCP and Dash Threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, plotly-dash, python-multithreading

I am trying to use Python to receive data using TCP and display these data on Dash. For that I created a thread for TCP and it is working fine. Also my dash is working fine but the problem is, when I read the queue.data in dash update, the queue is always empty! I think there is something wrong in TCP Thread. I am writing down my code. I would be grateful if someone can find the bug.
As I already mentioned, the dash is working right and it displays, if empty string, a random number every 1000 ms.

If there is any other solution to share data, I would be very thankful.

```
import socket
import threading
import queue
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Output, Input
import random


class ClientThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, client_socket, client_address, data_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client_socket = client_socket
        self.client_address = client_address
        self.data_queue = data_queue
        print("[+] New thread started for " + str(client_address))

    def run(self):
        print("Connection from: " + str(self.client_address))

        self.client_socket.send(b"\nWelcome to the server\n\n")

        data = b"dummydata"

        while len(data):
            data = self.client_socket.recv(2048)
            print("Client sent: " + data.decode('utf-8'))
            #elf.client_socket.send(b"You sent me: " + data.decode('utf-8'))

            # Put the received data into the queue
            self.data_queue.put('QUEUEU DATA')
            #self.data_queue.put(data.decode('utf-8'))

            self.data_queue.task_done()



        print("Client disconnected from: " + str(self.client_address))
        self.client_socket.close()

# Create and configure the Dash app
app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H6("This Dash has to display received data from TCP!"),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(id='random-number'),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1000,  # Interval in milliseconds (1000 ms = 1 second)
            n_intervals=0  # Initial value for n_intervals
        ),
    html.Div(id='my-output'),

])

# Create a queue to communicate data between threads
data_queue = queue.Queue()

@app.callback(Output(component_id='my-output', component_property='children'),
    Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')
)

def update_random_number(n_intervals):
    try:
        data2 = data_queue.get_nowait()
        return f'Received from client: {data2}'
    except queue.Empty:
        random_number = random.randint(1, 100)  # Generate a random number
        return f"Empty Queue: {random_number}"


host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5005

def run_server(data_queue):
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5005

    tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    tcpsock.bind((host, port))
    threads = []

    while True:
        tcpsock.listen(4)
        print("\nListening for incoming connections...")
        (clientsock, clientaddr) = tcpsock.accept()
        newthread = ClientThread(clientsock, clientaddr, data_queue)
        newthread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a thread for the server
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_server, args=(data_queue,))
    server_thread.start()
    data_queue.join()

    # Run the Dash app in the main thread
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```